# Calculate this limit without L'Hospital's rule or series expansion

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Calculating the limit as $x$ approaches $0$ using L'Hospital's rule or series expansion is straightforward, but how to evaluate the limit without either of those techniques.

How to calculate the following limit as $x$ approaches $0$:

$\dfrac{\ln(x+1)+1-e^x}{x^2}$

Comment: Is there any specific reason for asking, or just curiosity?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Okay, so exactly **what** are we allowed to know about the properties of $\ln(x)$ and $\exp(x)$? You can't expect an answer until we know the answer to **this** question

Comment: I suppose we can assume $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ln(x+1)}{x} = 1 $ and  $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{x} = 1 $

Comment: I am asking this question to see whether it is possible and what insights can be used to evaluate such a limit using algebraic manipulation

Comment: If you assume those two things, then you can just break the limit up into a product of limits. After all, if $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x \to a}g(x)=M$, then $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)g(x)=LM$.

Comment: Can you please clarify? how do you break $\frac{ln(x+1)+1-e^x}{x^2}$ into a product

Comment: You assumptions that $\lim_{x\to 0} \ln(x+1)/x = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0} (e^x-1)/x = 1$ are **not** sufficient to prove what y ou want to prove. You need to know **more** about $\ln$ and $\exp$. What algebraic manipulation is possible with only what you gave?

Answer (score 1):

This question boils down to showing that the limit $$L=\lim _{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}$$ exists. Using $e^x-1=t$ we can see that the above implies that $$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-\log(1+x)}{x^2}$$ and adding this to the first limit we get the desired limit in question as $-2L$. You can use binomial theorem and the definition $$e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$ to get $L=1/2$.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, using $e^t-1=t$ only implies $L = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t-ln(t+1)}{(ln(t+1))^2}$

Comment: @Emperoraeneas: but you can replace denominator by $t^2$ by multiplying the above limit with $\lim_{t\to 0}\left(\dfrac{\ln(1+t)}{t}\right)^2=1$.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!